# Using the Windows.Management namespace in C++ builder XE2

Tags: c++, wmi, c++builder-xe2

I am very new to C++ on Embarcadero XE2. Currently I want to transfer the following class
http://weblogs.asp.net/whaggard/archive/2006/02/11/438006.aspx

to c++ version.

But I wonder I can use System.Management on Embarcadero XE2, or I still have to use wbemidl.h to deal with WMI. (I have just given it a try and it returned Error: Management is not  a member of System)

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `System.Management` is a .Net namespace, C++ Builder not is a .Net development tool, so you can't use this namespace under c++ builder. The natural way to access the WMI from C++ is using COM directly using the interfaces defined in the wbemcli.h or wbemidl.h files.

Comment: Thank, I will do the way you suggested!